# Locus of vertex of moving parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, plane-curves

The parabolas $y^2=-12x$ and $y^2=12x$ touch each other at $(0,0)$. The parabola $y^2=-12x$ starts rolling on the parabola $y^2=12x$ (without slipping). Find the locus of the vertex of the moving parabola.

My Attempt:

The two parabolas are always going to have a common tangent at the point of contact. Is it possible to write an equation of a family of curves which touch this variable tangent?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63025/why-does-the-focus-of-a-rolling-parabola-trace-a-catenary

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32629/a-circle-rolls-along-a-parabola

Comment: @lab, those are distantly related, at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P(3t^2,6t)$ be any point on the parabola $y^2=12x$. The equation of tangent to the parabola at $P$  is

$ty=x+3t^2$ .

Now the vertex of the parabola (say $(h,k)$) which has rolled will be image of $(0,0)$ with respect to tangent line $ty=x+3t^2$.

$\frac{h-0}{1}=\frac{k-0}{-t}=-\frac{2(0-t(0)+3t^2)}{1+t^2}$

Thus, $t=-\frac{k}{h}$

Eliminating $t$ , we get

$h(h^2+k^2)+6k^2=0$

So required locus should be

$x(x^2+y^2)+6y^2=0$

Answer (score 4):

As noted [here](https://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/orthotomic/orthotomic.shtml) (*en Français*) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_curve#Geometrical_properties), the [roulette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette_(curve)) traced by a fixed point on a curve rolling on a copy of this curve is the same as the *orthotomic* (effectively a scaled *pedal curve*) with respect to that fixed point.

For the particular case of the parabola, the orthotomic (pedal) with respect to the vertex is called the *[cissoid of Diocles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cissoid_of_Diocles#As_a_pedal_curve)*.

[image: cissoid]

(image taken from [here](https://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/cissoiddroite/cissoiddroite.shtml))