# Parametrization of the curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, plane-curves, parametrization

A cycloid is a flat curve that is traced by point of the rim of a circle while the circle rolls without slippage on the line. Show that if the line is the axis $x$ and the circle has radius $a>0$, then the cycloid can be parametrized by $$\gamma (t)=a(t-\sin t, 1-\cos t)$$ Could you give me some hints how we could show that? I don't really have an idea what I could do...

Comment: possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133604/how-to-find-the-parametric-equation-of-a-cycloid

Comment: @Mary Star Certainly a duplicate. I looked at it and instantly gave my vote because of that lovely animation! Check it out, Mary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you here (with weak English) an explanation of the parametric you ask. In the figure below, your point $P(x,y)$ has started from the position $P_0$ at the coordinate origin.

By definition of cycloid the arc $\widehat{PQ}$ subtended by the angle $t$  (which is choose as parameter!) and the segment $\overline{P_0Q}$ have the same length equal to $at$. Now all is easy:
$$x=\overline {P_0Q}-\overline{SQ}=at-a\space cos(t-\frac{\pi}{2})=a(t-sin\space t)$$
$$y=\overline{SP}=\overline{SR}+\overline{RP}=a+a\space sin(t-\frac{\pi}{2})=a(1-cos\space t)$$

[image]

Comment: It is not strictly necessary but it's better, for understanding, if you let see first that the function is clearly periodic with period 2 $\ pi$ with which you work in the interval [0,2$\pi$]

Comment: Why does it stand that the length of the segment $\overline{P_0Q}$ is equal to $at$ ?

Comment: This is simply the formule for the arc of a circunference, it is known  equal to $r\alpha$ where $r$ is the radius and $\alpha$ is the angle which subtends the arc.

Comment: Why is this segment equal to the arc of a circumference?

Comment: By the very definition of cycloide. When the point $P(x,y)$ touch again the X-axis the circumference has crossed  exactly a lenght equal to its lenght $2a \pi$. It is maybe clearer if you make back the point till the origin (it seems to me more "intuitive" because of the condition "without slippage").

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!! :-)