# What is locus of a fixed point on a circle of radius $r$ rolling over the curve $y=\sin x$?

Tags: calculus, plane-curves, locus

What is locus of a fixed point on a circle of radius $r$ rolling over the curve $y=\sin x$? I have been struggling on the problem for many days, but I could not solve it. Geometrically, the locus seems to be a series of cycloid-looking figures mounted on the exterior of the sine curve, but analytically it seems very difficult to find the equation of the locus.

Comment: Since the motion you describe involves matching the circle's arclength (easy) to [the arclength of the sine curve](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45089/what-is-the-length-of-a-sine-wave-from-0-to-2-pi), you are drawn into evaluation of an elliptic function.  So computationally what you want to do is tractable, but analytically it is going to involve those elliptic functions.

Comment: I think there should be a condition on the radius of the circle. for large values of $r$ the circle will not move. The start point is to consider special cases and small intervals. For example you can consider only the interval from $x=0$ to $x= \pi$ and notice that the distance moved on both curves are equal. the arc length of $y=sinx$ is easy and the distance on the circle is $r \theta$. try to answer "where on $y=sinx$ the circle complete a revolution"

Comment: The point on the curve where the circle completes one revolution is given by ∫_0^x▒〖√(1+〖cos〗^2 ) x〗 dx=2πr

Comment: salam sajjad. did you see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing this confusion in the answers and comments, so I might as well address it first: elliptic *integrals* and elliptic *functions* are **not the same thing**, in much the same way that one does not consider trigonometric functions and inverse trigonometric functions to be the same group.

---

Having gotten that pet peeve out of my chest, here's a nice cartoon to help you (and more so me) relax:

[image: rolls over the hills]

---

Using the general approach given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32923), and using the arclength expression demonstrated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49576), the parametric equations for the "sinusoidal cycloid" can be expressed in matrix-vector format as

$$\begin{pmatrix}t\\\sin t\end{pmatrix}+\frac1{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}}\begin{pmatrix}1&-\cos t\\\cos t&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-r \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{r}E\left(t\mid\frac12\right)\right)\\r-r \cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{r}E\left(t\mid\frac12\right)\right)\end{pmatrix}$$

where $E(\phi\mid m)$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind, which is a nonelementary function.

Comment: Great plot! How did you do it?

Comment: I used *Mathematica* to generate the cartoon, @marty.

Answer (score 1):

It involves an elliptic integral of the second kind.

Let $M = M(\theta) = (\theta, \sin \theta)$ be the contact point. The tangent at this point is  $T = (1, -\cos \theta)$ so the center $I$ of the circle is such that $\vec{MI} = (\frac {r \cos \theta} {1+\cos ^2 \theta}, \frac {r} {1+\cos ^2 \theta})$.

The fixed point $P$ on the rolling circle is obtained for $M$ by rotation around $I$ of an angle $s$ equal to the length of $OM$ along the curves, that is $s = \int _0^\theta \sqrt{1 + \cos^2 \theta} d\theta$. Explicitly, $IP= (\frac {r \cos \theta} {1+\cos ^2 \theta} \cos s + \frac {r} {1+\cos ^2 \theta} \sin s , \frac {-r \cos \theta} {1+\cos ^2 \theta} \sin s + \frac {r} {1+\cos ^2 \theta} \cos s) $.

So the only step that makes the curve non-rational is the integral, which indeed is an elliptic function, impossible to express with elementary functions alone.

Comment: There is something wrong with the coordinates of M and I ;the distance MI does not come out to be r as it should be.Try distance formula and see for yourself.