# Find the locus of the point $P$ on the circumference of the circle which is on the origin at the initial position of the circle.

Tags: analytic-geometry, physics

> Consider the circle of radius $1$ with its centre at the point $(0,1)$. From this initial position, the circle is rolled along the positive $x$-axis without slipping. Find the locus of the point $P$ on the circumference of the circle which is on the origin at the initial position of the circle.

**My approach:**

Let us assume that the circle is moving with a constant velocity $v$. Then after time $t$, the distance travelled by the centre of the circle, as measured from the initial position is $d=vt$. Now let the point $P$ be at a new position $P'=(a,b)$.

This also implies that the centre of the circle is at $(d,1)=(vt,1)$.

Note that $(a,b)$ is a point of the circle having centre at $(vt,1)$ and radius $1$.

Therefore, $(a,b)$ must satisfy the equation of that circle. Now, the equation of that circle is $(x-vt)^2+(y-1)^2=1$. Thus, we have $(a-vt)^2+(b-1)^2=1$.

Also, a geometric approach helps us in showing that $$a=vt-\sin vt \text{ and } b=1-\cos vt.$$

But, what's the locus then?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622316/what-is-locus-of-a-fixed-point-on-a-circle-of-radius-r-rolling-over-the-curve

Comment: The locus is the set of points $P$ generated by rolling the circle. So in this case, it's just the curve generated by the parametric equations you obtained. (It's better known as a _cycloid_.)