# Finding parametric curves on a sphere

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

1. Is there some general method for finding such curves? Let's say I have a planar curve, how can I project it onto a sphere?
2. I am interested in a curve that starts at the south pole of a sphere, then wraps it in spiral motion and ends at the north pole. Is it possible to construct?

Comment: For any curve $\gamma$, the curve $\frac{\gamma}{||\gamma||}$ lies on the unit sphere.

Comment: Also, [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalSpiral.html) is the first result when googling "spiral on sphere".

Comment: The inverse of the [stereorgaphic projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StereographicProjection.html) will take any planar curve to a curve on the sphere.

Comment: For 2: see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9159).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your first question, suppose $\gamma$ is any curve.  Then the norm of $\frac{\gamma}{||\gamma||}$ is $\frac{||\gamma||}{||\gamma||} = 1$, so the image of $\frac{\gamma}{||\gamma||}$ lives on the unit sphere in your space.

Your second question can be answered with the help of stereographic projection.  We'll take a curve in the plane and project it onto the unit sphere.

[image]

(Image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).)

If we describe the plane with the polar coordinates $(R,\Theta)$, and the sphere with the coordinates $(\varphi,\theta)$, where $\varphi$ is the [zenith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenith) angle and $\theta$ the [azimuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth), then the map from the plane to the sphere is given by

$$
\begin{align}
\varphi &= 2 \arctan\left(\frac{1}{R}\right), \\
\theta  &= \Theta.
\end{align}
$$

If you'd like, this can be converted to Cartesian coordinates by

$$
\begin{align}
x &= \cos \theta \sin \varphi, \\
y &= \sin \theta \sin \varphi, \\
z &= \cos \varphi.
\end{align}
$$

As an example, if we take the logarithmic spiral defined in polar coordinates by $R = e^{\Theta/8}$, the Cartesian parametric curve describing its image on the sphere is

$$
\gamma(t) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
\cos t \,\sin \left(2 \arctan \left(e^{-t/8}\right)\right) \\
\sin t \,\sin \left(2 \arctan \left(e^{-t/8}\right)\right) \\
\cos \left(2 \arctan \left(e^{-t/8}\right)\right)
\end{array}\right).
$$

[image]

Answer (score 7):

1. Do you really mean circle, rather than sphere?
2. A parametrization with constant rate of increase along the $z$ axis is
   $(x,y,z)=\left( \sqrt{1-t^2}\cos (a \pi t), \: \sqrt{1-t^2} \sin (a \pi t), \: t \right), \: 0<t<1$, where the $a$ parameter controls the number of revolutions. This is with $a=5$:

[image: Spiral with a=5]

You can derive this by noting that $x \propto \cos(\cdot) $ and $y \propto \sin (\cdot)$. If $z$ is to increase in a linear fashion from -1 to +1 we can let $z=t$ for $t=-1 \dots 1$. Finally, since the spiral is to lie on the surface of a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, so it follows that $x=\sqrt{1-t^2}\cos (a \pi t)$ and $y=\sqrt{1-t^2} \sin (a \pi t)$

Comment: This figure is for the case $-1<t<1$ not for $0<t<1$.